# Can I make a Twitter Follow Button from an external JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, api, twitter

My site calls an external JavaScript file to create the footer on every page. I would like to include a follow button in the footer. However, all of the examples on the developer page are geared toward creating the button from an HTML file with embedded script, and I am not experienced enough with JS to figure out how to rewrite the code to work without the HTML. I have already tried storing the whole HTML blob as a string and writing it to the document. I also took the JS out of the blob and added it to the file, but that didn't work either.

Here is the HTML they provide, and I tried to extract

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/dbb0" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @dbb0</a>
<script>
    !function(d,s,id){
        var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if(!d.getElementById(id)){
            js=d.createElement(s);
            js.id=id;
            js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
        }
    }(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>
```

Comment: I think it would be best to load html from a file instead of JS.

Comment: Hassan, why would it be best?

Comment: So you're not mixing HTML and Javascript. This tends to get very messy and difficult to change/improve.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your main question: yes it's possible.

You should use the DOM, innerHTML (be careful with this) or jQuery to create a very similar html structure, and then add it to your document.

You should ask more specific questions to get further, this is too vague :)

Comment: That's interesting, because I'd say this answer is pretty vague. Maybe I should ask again and insert the word "How" at the beginning of the question.

Comment: Well, besides just adding the word how.. how about adding some code.. what did you try? You're not going to find a ton of people just writing code for you.

Comment: As I said, I tried using the code from the HTML that twitter provides. To be explicit, I've added it to the original post.

Comment: Ok getting a bit further. Now.. this is the original twitter code. Can you show what you've tried? Also, instead of saying 'it didn't work', can you elaborate on what happened? Errors? Nothing at all?

Comment: I executed only the javascript from an external file, which of course does not work. I don't know how to set up the anchor element from the JS file.